# MFC: how to show a welcome dialog first?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

When launch the program, I want to show a welcome dialog first before showing the main window. My current approach is like below.

```
BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{
    ...
    // The one and only window has been initialized, so show and update it
    m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    //m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
    // call DragAcceptFiles only if there's a suffix
    //  In an SDI app, this should occur after ProcessShellCommand

    CWelcomeDialog welcome_dialog;
    welcome_dialog.DoModal();

    m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

    return TRUE;
}
```

Towards the end of InitInstance(), originally it uses (SW_SHOW). At first, I try commenting it out but it still shows. So I change to (SW_HIDE). It works but has unpleasant visual artifacts. Is there way to stop showing the main window as early as possible?

Another issue is that when I hide main window and show the dialog, the dialog is not in the center position of the main window.

In general, how to implement a welcome dialog and to show it well-centered before anything else?

Comment: You've got the right idea: your "splash screen" belongs in `CMyApp::InitInstance()`.  Look here for a good example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35840/Splash-Screen-C-Class-using-MFC

Comment: Thank you. The example looks pretty good. I may study it more when I have more time. From a brief reading, it seems I only need to move it to the very beginning of InitInstance().

Comment: Why not just show the welcome dialog before creating the main window? And centering the dialog can easily be done by yourself.